# I want to stop shake animation after click on another image

Tags: java, android

I want to play animation one by one ,  when i click on any new image the previous image also shake , I want to stop previous image animation immediately click on any new image.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView dog, lion, cat, cow, elephant, horse, nextB, backB, settingB;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Animation animShake;

// Firebase analyticals
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Action bar hide
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

    // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    // find ids of items
    findId();

    // on click
    onClick();

    // Animation of shake of items when click
    animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);


}


private void onClick() {

    // lion click
    lion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();

            lion.startAnimation(animShake);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.lion);
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    // cow click
    cow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();
            cow.startAnimation(animShake);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.cow);
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    // cat click
    cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();
            cat.startAnimation(animShake);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.cat);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    // dog click
    dog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();
            dog.startAnimation(animShake);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.dog);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    // elephant click
    elephant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();
            elephant.startAnimation(animShake);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.elephant);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    // horse click
    horse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();

            horse.startAnimation(animShake);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.horse);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });


    settingB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}



// check is audio is playing already
public void check() {

    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();

    }
}



// find all ids here
private void findId() {
    dog = findViewById(R.id.dogImg);
    cat = findViewById(R.id.catImg);
    cow = findViewById(R.id.cowImg);
    lion = findViewById(R.id.lionImg);
    elephant = findViewById(R.id.elephantImg);
    horse = findViewById(R.id.horseImg);
    nextB = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
    nextB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    backB = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
    backB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    settingB = findViewById(R.id.setting);
}
```

When I click any new Image the previous image is also shake , how i stop it and shake image one at a time .  I tried many ways but i cannot find the solution , can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that keeps the last image clicked, create a metohd onClick that takes an Image in input to animate it, check if the last is different from the actual, if yes, stop the animation using lastClicked image and start the anim on the new, something like :

```
ImageView lastImageClicked = null

lion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check the condition is any audio is playing already
            check();
            animateImage(lion)

        }
    });
      
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
 private void animateImage(ImageView actualImage){
    if(lastClicked != null && actualImage == lastClicked)
      //block animation on lastclicked using his id
      .
      .
      .
    //startAnimation on the other image using actualImage id

    //set the lastClicked Image to actual
    lastClicked = actualImage

    
 }
```

Comment: to stop the animation,  what code is it?

Comment: To stop the animation on an imageview, call clearAnimation() on animating imageview to stop animation.
Like the answer by TabascoLosco, you can save a copy of animating imageview in a lastImageClicked instance. 
Using it you can cancel the previous animation before starting the next one.